# SQL queries SELECT

Tags: sql

How can I get all columns from these relations of tables post / Images/Categories and just the username and avatar from users?  ;

Images Table

```
images_id    images_name    
1            image1    
2            image2
```

Categories table

```
cate_id    name
1          vehicles    
2          home
```

Users table

```
users_id  username password email       avatar    
1         nour     1233     nour@gmail  image
```

Post Table

```
post_id title text images_id cate_id users_id    
1.      title text  1        1       1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT Post.*,Images.*,Categories.*, Users.username FROM Users LEFT JOIN Post >> tried this but that dose not work

Comment: @amanirose you need to go thru the sql beginner's guide once more. This should be a very basic join operation

Comment: @Steve thank you i am still a beginner

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a basic Join. You should read up on the basics of it:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

The examples here seem like the exact same problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

`PostTable` is the table that ties everything together in this schema. You can use that with an [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) to `SELECT` all data in the joined tables.

*How can I get all columns from these relations of tables post/Images/Categories and just the username and avatar from users*

In this case, we need to search by the `username` and `avatar`. For the sake of this example, let's assume `avatar` is a SQL String (since it was unclear). Then, you could do the following.

```
SELECT * FROM UsersTable
INNER JOIN PostTable ON UsersTable.users_id = PostTable.users_id
INNER JOIN CategoriesTable ON CategoriesTable.cate_id = PostTable.cate_id
INNER JOIN ImagesTable ON ImagesTable.images_id = PostTable.images_id
WHERE UsersTable.username = 'search_string' AND UsersTable.avatar = 'target_avatar';
```

Note, if `username` is unique then you don't actually need the `avatar` portion of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot i tried this query and worked...   SELECT Cateogries.*,Images.*,Post.*,Users.username,Users.avatar FROM Users
INNER JOIN Post ON Users.users_id = Post.users_id 
INNER JOIN Cateogries ON Cateogries.cate_id = Post.cate_id
INNER JOIN Images ON Images.images_id = Post.images_id

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to resolve your issue and I hope `SQL JOINS` are more clear to you now.